# Склонение сложных существительных с однобуквенным словом после дефиса

Tags: склонение, недопустимая-метка

Добрый день. Никак не могу найти правила склонения сложных существительных с дефисом, где после дефиса стоит одна буква. К примеру, седал-м - название препарата. Логика подсказывает, что нужно склонять только первое слово, но, быть может, есть какое-либо правило? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это заимствование, такие термины (медицинские)обычно не склоняются:" Показания к применению Седал-М" (http://www.sedal-m.ru/instruction.shtml). Но в разговорном языке, если термин хорошо освоен языком, т.е. часто употребляется, склоняется первая часть, а литера М, Д3 и т.д. не изменяется:"Пришёл в аптеку, а седала-м нет."

А лучше сказать:"А препарата Седал-М нет"